# DBI::mysql and File::Temp

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, temporary-files

I'm trying to load data into a MySQL database using the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement. On normal files, this works fine.

If I create a temporary file with `File::Temp`, store CSV data in it, close the file and then directly `LOAD` it into the database using

```
$dbh->do("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$tempfile' INTO TABLE $temptable" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',');
```

the last two records are reproducibly omitted. However, if I do anything with the tempfile between creation and `LOAD`ing, for example with

```
`touch $tempfile`;
```

everything works as expected.

Is this an issue with the MySQL driver having trouble with freshly created tempfiles? Is it a filesystem (ext4) issue, maybe a cache flush not happening in time? Am I missing something here?

**EDIT**: Actually, *all* records are omitted if the temporary CSV file is not created by a format-converter subroutine, but by hand as shown below. I also included the code for the database interaction. Note the commented `touch $tmpfh`, which, when uncommented, would make the example work.

Adding `UNLINK => 0` to `File::Temp->new()` does not make a difference.

```
my $tmpfh = File::Temp->new();
print $tmpfh <<EOT;
record1,textfield1
record2,textfield2
record3,textfield3
record4,textfield4
record5,textfield5
EOT

# `touch $tmpfh`; # uncomment this line to make it work

# get db handle
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$dbname:$dbserver", $username, $pwd);

# drop and recreate temp table
$dbh->do("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $temptable") or die;
$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE $temptable (
`id`       INT(11)      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`header`   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`sequence` MEDIUMBLOB)")
    or die;

# load data into temp table
my $nrecords = $dbh->do("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$tmpfh' 
INTO TABLE $temptable 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(header, sequence)")
    or die;

$dbh->disconnect();

printf "Loaded %d records from %s into %s on %s.\n", $nrecords, $tmpfh, $dbname, $dbserver;
```

Comment: Show the code for creating the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close the file handle to flush the buffer. Keep the "UNLINK => 0" if you want the file to remain when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: I forgot to do that. Thank you!